# How to map a subdomain to a tomcat 8 web application running on port 8086

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost, tomcat8

I have a subdomain test.example.com.
I have a java web application running in tomcat 8.5 on port 8086.

In /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml I have a virtual host defined like below.

```
<Host name="canicarry.thehatapps.com" appBase="webapps/SecondAmendmentSupporters-0.2" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="canicarry_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

I have an apache2 conf defines like below.
/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.example.com
        ServerAlias www.test.example.com.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.example.com/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/test.example.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

In public_html I have .htaccess defined like below.

```
RedirectPermanent / http://test.example.com:8086
```

My goal is to be able to hit the myapp-02 tomcat web app on port 8086 like so http://canicarry.thehatapps.com:8086

I'm not sure what's wrong but I get 404. I can't seem to resolve http://canicarry.thehatapps.com:8086 to my web app running in tomcat.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED-----------
Using this in my apache conf file helped but still running into issues.

```
<VirtualHost canicarry.thehatapps.com/*:80>
  ServerName canicarry.thehatapps.com
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8086/SecondAmendmentSupporters-0.2
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8086/SecondAmendmentSupporters-0.2
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type http://canicarry.thehatapps.com:8086, I'm taken to

> http://104.238.96.249:8086/SecondAmendmentSupporters-0.2/

Which is the full url to my tomcat application. However, when I append an endpoint, it doesn't resolve. In addition, the url should still be http://canicarry.thehatapps.com:8086. It shouldn't show the full url to the tomcat application instance.

For example, http://canicarry.thehatapps.com:8086/places should return a list of places from the service but it doesn't resolve the url.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<VirtualHost *:80>` is telling apache to listen on port `80`.

If you want the application to be exposed over port `8086` then you need to proxy the port `8086` to your tomcat server. You can do this using the `ajp_proxy` module of apache.

```
<VirtualHost test.example.com:8086>
  ServerName test.example.com
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /examples ajp://127.0.0.1:8086/examples
  ProxyPassReverse /examples ajp://localhost:8086/examples
</VirtualHost>
```

See below article for details

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-up-apache-webserver-proxy-in-front-of-apache-tomcat-on-red-hat-linux

Comment: Hi Tarun, that helped a bit but I'm still running into issues. I edited my post above with more details.